# Out Of Memory issue when adding image to picturebox

Tags: vb.net, memory

New to the forums - I've done a lot of research on this and tried a variety of different ways, but I keep receiving an out of memory issue on certain machines, not all machines, when trying to display an image in a picture box. My code is below, this gets called on an Ultragrid_AfterSelectChange event

```
Dim myImagePath As String = ""

If ThumbNail.Selected.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim rowSelected As UltraGridRow
    For Each rowSelected In ThumbNail.Selected.Rows
        Select Case folderType.ToLower
            Case "image", "scan"
                myImagePath = ThumbNail.Rows(rowSelected.Index).Cells(1).Value
                Try
                    If IO.File.Exists(myImagePath) Then
                        If Not IO.File.GetAttributes(myImagePath) = IO.FileAttributes.Normal Then
                            IO.File.SetAttributes(myImagePath, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
                        End If
                        Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(myImagePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
                        Dim bm As Image

                        bm = Image.FromStream(fs).Clone

                        'bm1 = bm
                        Application.DoEvents()
                        fs.Close()

                        ' SBD(12 / 29 / 2014)
                        If PictureBox.Image IsNot Nothing Then
                            Try
                                PictureBox.Image.dispose()
                                'PictureBox.Image = Nothing
                            Catch ex As Exception

                            End Try

                        End If
                        'SBD 12/29/2014

                        PictureBox.Image = bm
                        Application.DoEvents()
                        fs.Dispose()
                        fs = Nothing ' July 16, 2013 - SM

                        bm.Dispose()
                        bm = Nothing ' July 16, 2013 - SM

                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    If My.Settings.DebugMode = "True" Then
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Show Image", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to locate file: " & myImagePath & ". Contact your administrator.", "Show Image", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                    End If
                End Try

            Case Else
                'myImagePath = Application.StartupPath & "\Music.bmp"
                If ThumbNail.Rows(rowSelected.Index).Cells(1).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    If IO.File.Exists(ThumbNail.Rows(rowSelected.Index).Cells(1).Value) Then
                        Try
                            AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = ThumbNail.Rows(rowSelected.Index).Cells(1).Value
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show("Media player error.", "Windows Media Player", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        End Try

                    End If
                End If

        End Select
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Since you have file names apparently, if you use `PictureBox.ImageLocation` you wont have to worry about creating and disposing images. Since it is a loop though, only the last one will show.  Get rid of `DoEvents()` too.  Note that OOM can actually mean out of resources in this case.  Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see what you mean by using PictureBox.ImageLocation - the only problem I see with that is I cannot reduce the image size then to fit inside of my box. Also, my control for PictureBox is an UltraPictureBox, it does not have the imagelocation property.

Comment: The people that worked on this code did not have the faintest idea how the `Using` statement works.  Clearly they already had severe out-of-memory problems back 4 years ago, and did not solve them completely.  Looks like you inherited an albatross.  Only sensible way to move forward is a *thorough* code review by an experienced .NET programmer and a memory profiler to catch the overlooked ones.

Comment: These out of memory problems have been haunting them for years from my understanding.  I've inherited a lot of problems and I am slowly working through them.  I've gone through the same process that my clients do and they get the error as soon as they select a thumbnail.  My machine, of course being designed for development, has more memory and processing power than theirs does. I've been stepping through with the memory diagnostic tools running, and with each change of an image, my memory jumps slightly, based on image size, but goes back down to the baseline where it sits.